# Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 'xxxx'

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, port

How do I find the process that is listening on port 'xxxx' and kill it?

I have `RemoteForward 2022 remote.host:22` in my .ssh/config file.

Whenever I ssh into a remote server: `ssh staging-environment` I am getting this error: `Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 2022`

I need this port open for port forwarding.

How do I find the process that is listening on port 2022 and kill it?

UPDATE:

Output of `netstat -tulpn`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:83                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:84                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:85                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:86                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2022              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2023              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to see who is using port 2022 is

```
  sudo ss -ntp
```

First, you should not use nestat, which is by now obsolete (if you are on Linux, as I believe you are, but if you are on Unix just forget this); second, you should run the command as *sudo*, otherwise you will not have the authority to display the processes using the port; third, you should definitely **not** use the flag *u*, because this means looking at UDP ports, while you are getting an error on *ssh*, which is most definitely using TCP, not UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple methods to do this. netstat is a command line tool which should do what you want. A command line example would be something like:

`# netstat -tulpn`

This will lest ports on your system and which application is listening to it.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've added the output of netstat. There is no process listed for port 2022. Why would this be?

Comment: I think the problem may have to do with multiple old ssh connections. When I `ps -ef | grep ssh` I can see multiple sessions created by my user (and if they are listed, that means they are still active right?) and what looks to be some git processes running ...

Comment: That could be the case. If you have old connections dotted about they would need to be pointed at something. If you want to start digging into your ssh connections this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199089/find-out-how-much-ssh-connections-currently-exist

Comment: Out of interest have you checked to see if anything is already listed for it under your router? Might have left yourself a note saying what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am currently getting around this error is to log into my server and `ps -ef | grep ssh` and kill all of the sessions spawned by my user.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick one-liner will do it

```
for pid in `netstat -tunpl | awk '{print $4, $7}' | grep ':2022' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f1`; do kill -9 $pid; done
```